# How to load more posts without loading the whole page again?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, load

In my home page, I'm showing the last three rows of my table via this code:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT  id, title, date, text FROM news WHERE hshs=1 ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT $p") or die(mysql_error());
```

Where `$p` comes from:

```
$p = $_GET['page'];

if ( empty($p) ) {
    $p = 2;
    $more = 4;
} 
else{
    if ( $p < $postnum ) {
        $more = $p + 2;
    }
    else{
        $finish = 1;
    }       
}
```

and `$postnum` is number of the rows.

Then, I have this line to load more posts:

```
if ( $finish != 1 ) {
    echo '<center><strong><a id="loadmore" href="?page='.$more.'">Load more posts...</a></strong></center>';
}
```

This does its job beautifully. But I have a problem. I don't want to load the whole page again to load more posts. Because this will show the page again from the top of it! I want the page to stay where it is without scrolling the user to the top of it, and then loads more posts.

Hope you will understand me! :)

Comment: Use `ajax` to load data without refreshing the page. Reference: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: Please try http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: Here is an example http://www.sanwebe.com/2013/03/loading-more-results-from-database

Answer (score 0):

Step 1) Call an Ajax request on click of "Load more posts..".

Step 2) PHP will return more posts as response to Ajax request.

Step 3) Append Ajax result in appropriate div (preferably using jQuery).

**Note**: Use limit in MySQL query for proper paging mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

Use [jQuery](https://jquery.com/):

```
jQuery( document ).on( 'click', '#loadmore', function() {

    jQuery.ajax({

        url: "./path-to-your-sql-load",
        data: {

            ajax: '1',
            page: '<?php echo $page+1; ?>'

        },
        method: 'get',
        success: function( response ) {

            console.log( response );
            jQuery( '#results' ).append( response );

        }

    });

} );
```

And in your SQL load you can check if it is ajax like this:

```
if( $_GET[ 'ajax' ] == '1' ):

    // ajax

else:

    // no ajax

endif;
```